# How to pre-fill a NSTableView bound to an ArrayController in a Core Data ( Document based)

Tags: nstableview, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsarraycontroller

Here is my problem:
I have a Core Data- Document based program with ARC ( Automatic Reference Counting);
I want the tableView shows some data at the beginning.
but I receive nothing. 
Here is what I have done:

1- I made a core data with Entity: MyData

[image]

2- then I added a NSArrayController and bound it to managedObjectContext and MyData

[image]

[image]

3-  I bonded the arrayController to col0:

[image]

4- then made and outlet and  added @synthesize for the arrayController :

[image]

5- Finally added this code:

> - (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController {
>
>   [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
>
>   for (NSUInteger i=0; i<5; i++) {
>
>   ```
>   [myArrayController add:self];
>
>   [myArrayController setSelectionIndex: i];
>
>   [myArrayController setValue:@"test" forKeyPath:@"selection.col0"];
>
>   NSLog(@"%lu",[myArrayController selectionIndex]);
>   ```
>
>   } }

But this is the problem: nothing happens and the SelectionIndex shows strange numbers!!

[image]

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one month nobody answered me !  finally I could handle it:

> NSError* error;
>
> ```
> NSInteger count=0;
>
> NSNumber* N=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:0];
>
> NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
>
> NSEntityDescription * entityMyData  = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyData"
>                                                   inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
>
> [fetchRequest setEntity:entityMyData];
>
>
> count=[self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
>
>
>
>     if (count==0 ) {
>         
>
>         for (NSInteger i=count+1; i<RowsToAdd+count+1; i++) {
>
>             N=@(i);
>
>             managedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyData"
>                                                           inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
>
>             [managedObject setValue:N forKey:@"col0"];
>
>             [managedObject setValue:N forKey:@"col1"];
>
>             
>         }
>
>        
>       
>     }
> ```